# How to display uploaded Dicom image metadata in detailed view in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am a new to coding and working on a small Django project in which I want to display Dicom image metadata. I included FileField in the Django model to upload a Dicom image and I want to display the uploaded Dicom image metadata in Generic detailed view. I tried overriding the context method and accessing the image path but getting an error. How do I proceed with it? Please help!

**#My model**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ailment = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_tested = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='.',default='download.jpg')
    dicom = models.FileField(upload_to='dicom/',null=True)
```

**#My Detailed view**

```
class PatientDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Patient

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        medinfo = dict()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dcpimg = imageio.imread(self.dicom.path)
        for keys in dcpimg.meta:
            medinfo[keys] = str(dcpimg.meta[keys])
        context['medinfo'] = medinfo
        return context
```

**##Iam getting this error**

```
AttributeError: 'PatientDetailView' object has no attribute 'dicom'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `self.dicom.path`, self here refers to PatientDetailView class.

Try calling:

```
self.model.dicom.path
```